# Passing a variable into require() with webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

So right now I am using webpack to bundle my js, and I am doing this

```
<div>
    {projectsJSON.map((project) => {
        return <Project title={project.title}
                        description={project.description}
                        image_url={require(project.image_url)}
               />
        })}
</div>
```

Where image_url is a relative path to the image. However the require statement is not working, and I think I understand why, since webpack statically analyzes dependencies, and by passing in a variable it is unable to do this. But I want to avoid explicitly requiring the image files if possible.

Comment: What is `Project` doing with the image URL? I'm not quite sure why you need to `require` it if it's just a string?

Comment: @MattHolland Project is using the image url in the src of an img tag, so for webpack to bundle that image, I would need to require it.

Comment: How many different `image_url` you have? And how often you need to add new `image_url`'s

Comment: @DmitryYaremenko I only have about 4-5, but I was just looking for a more elegant solution if possible, so that I only have to specify the url in my projectJSON and require them dynamically.

Comment: Does this help at all? https://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html I use `require.context()` to build a bundle of unit test files, using a regex to select all files with a specific suffix in the filename.